# Calculating volume of sphere using compute variable in SPSS

Tags: formula, volume, spss

I'm still fairly basic at stats and usually use a combination of R and SPSS. I've been advised to use SPSS to calculate the volumes of several shapes I have in my data. I have a column called BAshape then four columns called BAheight, BAwidth, BAdepth and BAdiameter.

I have been able to calculate the volume of the cuboids and create a new volume column by using Compute Variable with:

```
   IF BAshape = "Cuboid" 
   volume = BAheight * BAwidth * BAdepth
```

However the other shapes are cylinder, cone and sphere. I only have the diameter measurement not the radius so this needs halving but I thought I'd try it first with diameter to see if the formula works.... which it doesn't. This is what I have been trying in Compute Variable

```
  IF BAshape = "Sphere" 
  Volume = 4/3*3.14*BAdiameter^3
```

However I get the error code

> The expression ends unexpectedly.

I'm using IBM SPSS 22.

Answer (score 1):

In `SPSS` the power operator is in fact `**` and not `^` as you have.

The full error message you should be receiving:

> Warning # 206 in column 12.  Text: ^ 
>   An invalid character has been found on a command.
>
> Error # 4381 in column 12.  Text: ^ 
>   The expression ends unexpectedly. 
>   Execution of this command stops.

And from which it should be evident that the error is in fact due to the (incorrect) power operator being used.

Comment: Thank you I was assuming it was the same as excel! Is there a way to format it so that 
IF BAshape = "Cuboid" Volume = BAheight * BAwidth * BAdepth
and IF BAshape = "Sphere"  Volume = 4/3*3.14*BAdiameter**3

at the moment I can only get one or the other to display.

Comment: Note your formula for a sphere is incorrect. Don't understand your second question...

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure you're using the radius and not the diameter.